# Delete record from core data not working?

Tags: ios, objective-c, database, core-data

I am working with core data, when I deleting record from DB it's not working.
Entity name : Entity
Attributes : id, date, title

```
- (void) getData {

NSFetchRequest * fetReq = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Entity"];
NSError * fetchErrorObj;
NSArray *result = [self.ad.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetReq error:&fetchErrorObj];

NSLog(@"array count is %lu", result.count);

NSMutableArray *idArr = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
NSMutableArray *titleArr = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
NSMutableArray *dateArr = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

for (int i=0; i<result.count; i++) {

    self.storedManagedObj = [result objectAtIndex:i];

    [idArr addObject:[self.storedManagedObj valueForKey:@"id"]];
    [titleArr addObject:[self.storedManagedObj valueForKey:@"title"]];
    [dateArr addObject:[self.storedManagedObj valueForKey:@"date"]];

}
self.idArray = sidArr;
}
```

To delete record...

```
- (IBAction)deleteRecord:(UIButton *)sender {

NSNumber *value=[NSNumber numberWithInt:[[self.idArray objectAtIndex:0] intValue]];
NSLog(@"%@", [self.idArray objectAtIndex:0]);
NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:@"Entity"];
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"id == %@", value];
NSLog(@"predicate :%@", predicate);
[request setPredicate:predicate];
NSLog(@"request :%@", request);
NSError *error = nil;
NSArray *result = [self.ad.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
NSLog(@"result: %@", result);
if (!error && result.count > 0) {
    for(NSManagedObject *managedObject in result){
        NSLog(@"managedObject :%@", managedObject);
        [self.ad.managedObjectContext deleteObject:managedObject];
    }

    //Save context to write to store
    [self.ad.managedObjectContext save:nil];
}


}
```

I am getting result like this
predicate :id == 38
request : (entity: Entity; predicate: (id == 38); sortDescriptors: ((null)); type: NSManagedObjectResultType; )
result :(
)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is pretty clear. It states that you need to specify SortDescriptor to your FetchRequest

```
    NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:@"Entity"];
    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"<#Sort key#>"
                                                                   ascending:YES];
    request.sortDescriptors = @[sortDescriptor];
```

OR

```
NSArray *sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: sortDescriptor, nil];
[request setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
```

Read : [NSFetchRequest without sort descriptors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3397667/nsfetchrequest-without-sort-descriptors)

**EDIT:**

As OP isn't concerned about sorting the result in any specific order and the question lacks the description of entity and the only field that I can see in question is id updating my answer to use id in sort descriptor field

```
[[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"id" ascending:YES];
```

**EDIT 2:**

```
NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:@"Entity"];
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"id == %@", [self.idArray objectAtIndex:0]];
```

Issue in the code was :

```
NSNumber *value=[NSNumber numberWithInt:[[self.idArray objectAtIndex:0] intValue]];
```

OP was trying to create a `NSNumber` from an object in `self.idArray` using `intValue` which means idArray is a array of `String` and not `NSNumber`. That means `id` is saved as String in core data and not as NSNumber.

In predicate however OP was trying to pass `NSNumber` to compare with id. Since id is `String` and passed argument is `NSNumber` comparison was failing hence was not returning any objects.

Comment: Bro what is sort key

Comment: @ios-developer : Name of the field in Entity based on which results needs to be sorted. Because in your case sorting isn't important specify any field in Entity like name

Comment: you can specify key as "id"

Comment: NSNumber *value=[NSNumber numberWithInt:[[self.idArray objectAtIndex:0] intValue]];
NSLog(@"%@", [self.idArray objectAtIndex:0]);
NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:@"Entity"];  NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"id" ascending:YES];  request.sortDescriptors = @[sortDescriptor];
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"id == %@", value];
NSLog(@"predicate :%@", predicate);
[request setPredicate:predicate];
NSLog(@"request :%@", request);  But the result in empty

Comment: @ios-developer : Whats the issue buddy ??

Comment: Are you sure NSArray *result = [self.ad.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error]; returning array

Comment: Yes, it's returning array.

Comment: Whats the count of it ??

Comment: result.count = 0;

Comment: @ios-developer : if the count is 0 that means there is no entity in core data matching your predicate so how will it delete anything buddy ?? Control will never enter for loop

Comment: But I am getting request like this, request :<NSFetchRequest: 0x6080000c2e60> (entity: Entity; predicate: (id == 37); sortDescriptors: ((
    "(id, ascending, compare:)"
)); type: NSManagedObjectResultType; )

Comment: @ios-developer : The only issue in code I have told you the fix So code is fine now. When u call getData you sure there is a entity with id = 37 ???

Comment: Yes, this is my array...id = (
    36,
    37,
    38,
    39,
    40,
    41,
    42,
    43,
    44,
    45,
    46,
    47,
    48
)

Comment: @ios-developer : Gimme a moment lemme check

Comment: @ios-developer : Can you use the code in my Edit 2 Ill tell you whats wrong if my code works

Comment: @ios-developer : Am glad I could be of help :) Happy coding

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155877/discussion-between-sandeep-bhandari-and-ios-developer).

Comment: @ios-developer : Updated answer with reason for failure of predicate for future references